# Add Memtest86+ v6.10 in Grub2, boot failed by bad shim signature

Tags: ubuntu, debian, grub, memtest86+

Using [Debian 11.6.0 netinst](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/) running as a qemu VM  with UEFI boot mode. I'd like to add [Memtest86+ v6.10](https://memtest.org/) in the Grub2 menu

```shell
curl -OL --output-dir /tmp https://www.memtest.org/download/v6.10/mt86plus_6.10.binaries.zip

unzip -d /tmp /tmp/mt86plus_6.10.binaries.zip

cp /tmp/memtest64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/

cat >> /etc/grub.d/40_custom << EOF
menuentry 'Memtest86+ v6.10' {
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod fat
  set root='hd0,gpt1'
  chainloader (\$root)/EFI/memtest64.efi
}
EOF

update-grub
```

Reboot the VM, when the Grub menu appears, selecting the `Memtest86+ v6.10` entry fails to boot with a message "error: bad shim signature"

I have also tried another approach using `efibootmgr`

```shell
efibootmgr --create --disk=/dev/vda --part=1 --label="Memtest86+ v6.10" --loader='\EFI\memtest64.efi'
```

When booting the VM, select "UEFI Firmware Settings". Then navigate to the "Boot Manager Settings". Select "Memtest86+ v6.10". The screen just blink quickly but nothing happened. As if the `memtest64.efi` image is not bootable.

**QUESTION** How to add Memtest86+ 6.10 in the Grub menu and have it bootable in UEFI with Secure boot? The v6.10 changelog says "Add support for Secure Boot Signing". It does work if I boot the `mt86plus_6.10_64.iso` from an USB drive on a physical computer with UEFI + Secureboot. But unfortunately, there is no instruction to add `memtest64.efi` on an existing Linux.

Comment: Secure Boot != Secure Boot. Which keys does your VM trust, and which the PC where it boots? Is the file actually signed?

Comment: I suppose binaries which are secure boot compatible are signed by Microsoft key by default. I was able to install Debian 11 server with UEFI + Secureboot. without doing anything extra.

Answer (score 2):

Maintainers explicitly confirm that my reading of the change log is correct in [this issue](https://github.com/memtest86plus/memtest86plus/issues/283):

> While Memtest86+ 6.10 now supports Secureboot *signing*, the binary is not currently *signed* by Microsoft.

(Emphasis not mine)

So if it worked on a PC that supposedly has Secure Boot enabled, this PC does not have effective Secure Boot. Maybe it’s an MSI board? They implemented “Fake Secure Boot”, it was all over the media. See [this statement from MSI](https://us.msi.com/blog/statement-on-secure-boot).

If you want, you can sign the file yourself, then trust the certificate for Secure Boot. This process is quite involved and not keeping the signing key secure can easily compromise Secure Boot on this machine entirely.

Comment: Thanks, now this explains everything. Most notably, the Memtest86+ maintainers should emphasize on the v6.10 changelog that Secureboot is supported but not signed by Microsoft. In my case Secureboot did work as it rejected the Memtest86+ binary, the machine is a qemu VM (using `virt-install`), the UEFI nvram is emulated. If I don't add the Memtest86+ binary that VM could install successfully Debian 11.6.0 netinst  (UEFI + Secureboot)